# Spherical line through two points

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Given two vectors $u$ and $v$ in unit sphere $S^2$, I need to find *the* point $w\in S^2$ such that $L_w$ is the line through $u$ and $v$. My question is how can there be *the* point $w$ if a spherical line through $u$ and $v$ is supposed to contain infinitely many points $w$. Or am I not on the same page with something?

Comment: I imagine the notation $L_w$ means the line that results from taking the plane through the origin that is orthogonal to $w,$ then taking the intersection of that with the sphere. In which case there are two solutions, $w$ and its antipodal point.

Comment: Thanks, figured this out as well.